# Single View IOS 7 Memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, xcode5

I am trying to write a simple ios7 single-view app. The view controller has an UI image view taking up the whole screen, with two buttons taking up the entire left and right side of the screen. In essence, I want to be able to scroll through an array of images by clicking on the right side for the next sequential image, and the left side for the previous sequential image.

This app works, but it seems that the pointers in the code for my buttons aren't being derefenced. Or something else, I'm not really sure. Every time I go on to a new page, more and more memory is heaped up until it's running at over 700mb RAM. Please help me understand this memory allocation problem better. After running a profile of the project, it seems all the memory is being used by "All Anonymous VM"

Here is the code for the view controller.

```
#import "ABCViewController.h"
#import "ABCPage.h"

@interface ABCViewController ()

@end

@implementation ABCViewController

int current = 0;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
ABCPage *A = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
A.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
ABCPage *B = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
B.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
ABCPage *C = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
C.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"c.png"];
ABCPage *E = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
E.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"e.png"];
ABCPage *F = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
F.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"f.png"];
ABCPage *G = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
G.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"g.png"];
ABCPage *H = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
H.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"h.png"];
ABCPage *I = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
I.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"i.png"];
ABCPage *J = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
J.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"j.png"];
ABCPage *K = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
K.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"k.png"];
ABCPage *L = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
L.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"l.png"];
ABCPage *M = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
M.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"m.png"];
ABCPage *N = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
N.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"n.png"];
ABCPage *O = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
O.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o.png"];
ABCPage *P = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
P.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"p.png"];
ABCPage *Q = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
Q.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"q.png"];
ABCPage *R = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
R.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"r.png"];
ABCPage *S = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
S.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"s.png"];
ABCPage *T = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
T.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t.png"];
ABCPage *U = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
U.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"u.png"];
ABCPage *V = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
V.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"v.png"];
ABCPage *W = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
W.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w.png"];
ABCPage *X = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
X.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"];
ABCPage *Y = [[ABCPage alloc] init];
Y.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"y.png"];


self.myBook = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.myBook addObject:A];
[self.myBook addObject:B];
[self.myBook addObject:C];
[self.myBook addObject:E];
[self.myBook addObject:F];
[self.myBook addObject:G];
[self.myBook addObject:H];
[self.myBook addObject:I];
[self.myBook addObject:J];
[self.myBook addObject:K];
[self.myBook addObject:L];
[self.myBook addObject:M];
[self.myBook addObject:N];
[self.myBook addObject:O];
[self.myBook addObject:P];
[self.myBook addObject:Q];
[self.myBook addObject:R];
[self.myBook addObject:S];
[self.myBook addObject:T];
[self.myBook addObject:U];
[self.myBook addObject:V];
[self.myBook addObject:W];
[self.myBook addObject:X];
[self.myBook addObject:Y];

self.imageView.image = A.picture;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)previousButton:(UIButton *)sender
{

if (current > 0) {
current--;
ABCPage *currentPage = [self.myBook objectAtIndex:current];
self.imageView.image = currentPage.picture;
}

}

- (IBAction)nextButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
if (current < 23) {
current++;
ABCPage *currentPage = [self.myBook objectAtIndex:current];
self.imageView.image = currentPage.picture;
}

}
@end
```

Comment: You are creating and loading the images all at once. What do you expect to happen? How do you think this memory is supposed to be released?

Comment: First, simplify your method such as self.myBook = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:A,B,..., nil];

Comment: @Abizem how do I create and load the images more properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way its working is that as soon as you place an ABCPage into your myBook array, the array does a +1 on the ABCPage; this 'retain' will stop the object being deallocated.  Your page references an image so the image is not deallocated.  Furthermore when you assign a page's image to your self.imageView, it becomes +2 for the duration of it being set.

If I remember correctly, you need to tell the view holding the image view that it needs update with

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay]
```

otherwise the screen won't show the new image.

The reason why the Anonymous VM memory is going high is that for every UIImage, there is a peer memory area allocated by the VM subsystem to "back" the image with memory comprising the image data.  When the UIImage is released, the peer memory is released.

Doing adjustments to reduce memory whilst keeping quality and speed balanced off well is tricky.  I recommend first trying it by loading the image each time it is needed, and having no array to store them in advance.  This means you'll do +1 and -1 per image as you go through.  I would also issue a setNeedsDisplay after each page change.  You need to first get on top of the memory leak and then work forwards from there.

It sounds like the images are all too big for memory, so maybe a cache is needed for the images near the page you are currently at.  This could be your following step.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a UICollectionView with custom cells for this, it will work better for this specific case.

UICollectionViews have something called reusable cells, this means that it will not keep in memory cells that are not being used. And it will reuse existing ones when possible. It will just create new ones if necessary.

UICollectionView has a similar way to work to the UITableView this in very general terms.

Take a look of the documentation for UICollectionView even you can go further down and add swipe gesture recognizer to your app which is a common approach to switch between views horizontally arranged.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Related to you memory leak just make ABCPage *currentPage a property instead of instantiated it every time in next and previous. Make it a property in your class declaration and just assign it when you do ABCPage *currentPage you are creating new instances and for what you are mentioning this ones are not being released from memory.